# How to detect if form is submitted, when form function is called twice

Tags: 7, forms

I have simple form in aside block:

```
function my_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['save'] = array(
'#value' => t('Save'),
'#type' => 'submit'
);
return $form;
```

How can I detect (in this function), whether the form was submitted?
 I tried to add this line:

```
  $is_currently_submitted = !empty($form_state['input']);
```

But the problem, is that function my_form is called twice after submision, and in first call, the array $form_state['input'] is not empty, and in  second call it is empty. $_REQUEST array is empty in second call of function, too.
How can I then make changes in my form based on fact, whether the form was submitted or not?

Comment: Your form function is called twice during the submit process because first call is for build the form and compare sent values with the built form (very short explanation); second call is to build again the form in a fresh state to show it to the user again (after submission you usually see the same form again, unless a you use a redirection). Anyway, why you need to detect if the form is been built for a sumission process or for first time?

Comment: I forget, is there not a `$form_state['submitted']`? But yeah, what @tunic said. The second build is the form being built fresh for display. If you want code to run only when the form has been submitted, you've already got it. Is it possible you're trying to rebuild the _same_ form to show straight back to the user? If so, set `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` in your form's submit function

Comment: @tunic - I need to  add custom text inside the form for visitor: "Thank you for submitting the form". It is not status messages, but custom text inside the form

Comment: @Clive - thank you, solution with $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; in form submit function works. Could you write it as answer so I can mark it as solution?